# Cant connect to an app using Mesos-DNS

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

```
{
"id": "sparkslave",
"instances": 1,
"cpus": 1,
"mem": 512,
"constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]],
"cmd": "/root/spark-1.5.0/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://sparkmaster.marathon.mesos:7077 && tail -f /var/log/messages"
}
```

shouldn't sparkmaster.marathon.mesos resolve and connect to the IP where sparkmaster is running?

sparkmaster is another application being run through Marathon.

Comment: With Mesos DNS you should specify port or use SRV DNS request.

Answer (score 0):

When using `mesos-dns`, you should add your `mesos-dns` host ip to `/etc/resolv.conf`, so that your dns request can be handled by `mesos-dns`